# How can I handle undefined JSON data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is the code:

```
if (data.result.parameters.q === undefined ) {
    colsole.log('undefined')
}
//I also tried
if (data.result.parameters.q === null) {
    //   colsole.log('undefined')
// }
```

Have tried using null and undefined but none works.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?  If one of the earlier objects in the chain is null it will throw an error.  Otherwise you could `console.log(data.result.parameters.q)` and test for whatever it spits out

Comment: `console.log(data.result.parameters.q)` is really undefined?

Comment: What is `colsole`?

Comment: Typo with `colole` for a start. Also, if any of the parent objects like `parameters` are missing it won't _reach_ `q` to test it, so make sure you test for those too: `if (data && data.result && data.result.parameters && data.result.parameters.q === undefined )...`

Comment: Also, this has _nothing_ to do with JSON _unless_ you've forgotten to parse some JSON to an object which is also why it would fail the test.

Comment: Maybe your data object is undefined so you cant ask .result of undefined etc.

Comment: See similar question: [javascript test for existence of nested object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

Answer (score 1):

`a === undefined` doesn’t necessarily check for `undefined` since you could set `var undefined = {}`.

Use either the [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) or [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator (strict equality `===` isn’t necessary):

```
if(data.result.parameters.q == void(0) || typeof data.result.parameters.q == 'undefined')
    console.log('data.result.parameters.q is undefined');
```

How does your data actually look? Are you sure that `data`, `data.result` and `data.result.parameters` are set? There are plenty ways to check, like [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or general [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

```
if(data.hasOwnProperty('result') && data.result && data.result.hasOwnProperty('parameters'))
    // now we can check if there is q in data.result.parameters
```

Also note there’s a spelling error in your code: it’s `console`, not `colsole`.

Comment: up voted with note that "undefined" is read-only in modern browsers.